# Iterate sum of two squares

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for an efficient way to iterate over the infinite non-decreasing sequence defined by `a^2+b^2` where `a`, `b` are both positive integers. What I mean by iterate here, is that given an existing list of `n` entries, the algorithm should efficiently (I'm hoping for `O(log(m))`, where `m=a^2+b^2`) find the next entry.

The start of this list is: 1^2+1^2=2, 1^2+2^2=5, 2^2+2^2=8, 1^2+3^2=10, 2^2+3^2=13, 1^2+4^2=17, ...

Here's the python code used to generate these entries (the first 100 are correct):

```
xs=[]
for i in range(1, 100):
    for j in range(i, 100):
        xs.append((i**2+j**2, i, j))
xs.sort()
```

I've looked at the start of the list and can't see any pattern at all. Anyone know an algorithm to do this?

[edit] Upon some searching, I found [Cornacchia's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) which requires computing a quadratic residue. However I'm still hoping for something better, as we already know the previous numbers during iteration.

Comment: Just to clarify you want to iterate over them in increasing size order?

Comment: So my given `N` which is sum of squares for unknown `x` and `y` you want to find `M` which is sum of squares for `x+1`, `y` or `x`, `y+1` ?

Comment: @Chris: non-decreasing, I want to count duplicate entries as well, an example being 50=1^2+7^2=5^2+5^2

Comment: Ah yes. I'd missed that case in thinking about it. It does indeed seem to be incredibly tricky though. :(

Comment: Build 2d array one dimension for x another for y. You access time will be O(1). But it will take you N^2 to calculate them

Comment: @evhen14: how do you work out what order to get them out in though? That will just be a way of storing the calculated results, not getting them in the right order.

Comment: if not a secret: what do you want it for? (maybe there is some simpler solution)

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: There isn't a purpose, it's just a similar problem to iterating regular numbers.

Comment: Hi. This seems pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74784521/find-nth-smallest-sum-of-two-squares-numbers/ which has some interesting answers.

Answer (score 2):

The `isSumOfSquares` function returns `True` if *n* can be written as a sum of squares greater than zero and `False` otherwise, based on an algorithm from Edsgar Dijkstra's 1976 book *The Discipline of Programming*: *x* sweeps downward from the square root of *n*, decreasing when the sum of the squares is too large, and *y* sweeps upward from 1, increasing when the sum of the squares is too small.

```
from math import sqrt

def isSumOfSquares(n):
    x, y = int(sqrt(n)), 1
    while x >= y:
        if x*x + y*y < n: y = y + 1
        elif x*x + y*y > n: x = x - 1
        else: return True
    return False

filter(isSumOfSquares, range(1,100))
```

This returns the list [2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 18, 20, 25, 26, 29, 32, 34, 37, 40, 41, 45, 50, 52, 53, 58, 61, 65, 68, 72, 73, 74, 80, 82, 85, 89, 90, 97, 98]. I discussed a similar question at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/01/05/the-sum-of-two-squares/).

Comment: Running through every possible value to see if it's a sum of squares doesn't seem particularly efficient (and you'd probably have to change it a bit to detect duplicates - e.g. `50 = 1^2+7^2 = 5^2+5^2`).

Comment: It's O(sqrt(n)) to determine if n is on the list. To detect duplicates, just keep going after you find the first.

Answer (score 0):

In thinking about this I've assumed two things. The first is that for any a^2+b^2 that a>b. This is just because trivially (a,b) is in the same place in the ordering as (b,a) so you don't need to consider both.

Also the explanations are easier if a or b is allowed to be 0. These cases can easily be taken out in the real algorithm.

My thinking is that you should be able to do something based on looking at `m=a+b` and saying that for a given m the smallest sum of squares is `m^2/2` (when they are equal) and the largest is `(m-1)^2` with the obvious ordering between the two. You could then do a sort of merge sort between these to find the next one.

My thinking is that if you look at `m=a+b` then for any given m you can create an ordered list of the sums of squares for all `a+b=m`. The reason is that we know that the sum is a maximum when `a` or `b` is 0 and a minimum when `a=b=m/2`. This means we can trivially generate a series of lists of ordered sums of squares `L(m)`.

We also know the maximum and minimum entries in L(m) so we don't need to start considering those lists until we are in that range.

It will still mean potentially a lot of list to consider at higher values but it is still better than a more brute force approach.

I'm not sure if there is a better way once you have these list though to work out which one you need to select from. I think probably not though you might be able to make some guesses based on the distributions of numbers in the lists but I can't think of a way to formalise them in a nice way.

To give a more visual example of things then

```
List      Lowest value    Highest value
L(0)            0  (0,0)        0  (0,0)
L(1)            1  (1,0)        1  (1,0)
L(2)            2  (1,1)        4  (2,0)
L(3)            5  (2,1)        9  (3,0)
L(4)            8  (2,2)        16 (4,0)
L(5)            13 (3,2)        25 (5,0)
L(6)            18 (3,3)        36 (6,0)
L(7)            25 (4,3)        49 (7,0)
L(8)            32 (4,4)        64 (8,0)
```

So to start at 0 you only need to consider items in L(0), then that is exhausted and you move onto L(1). Then that is exhausted, etc. THen while working through L(3) you find that you are looking at the last of L(3) is 9 which is greater than the lowest in L(4) so you look at both those lists.

When you have just put in (5,0) and (4,3) for 25 you then will be considering things in L(6) and L(7). As you go higher you will be considering more lists as the lists start to contain more items over a larger range (eg the number 10,000 is in the range for L(100) (just about) and L(141) (which starts at 9941).

I should also note that you don't need to calculate the whole list in advance, you can easily make it a lazy iterator to calculate only the number at the front of the list since that is the only one you ever want.