# find nth smallest sum of two squares numbers

Tags: algorithm

It is an algorithm coding: x = a^2 + b^2, a,b is positive integers. Find f(n), the nth smallest x.

We know that f(1) = 1^2 + 1^2; f(2) = 1^2 + 2^2; f(3) = 2^2 + 2^2....

My idea is update a,b by comparing (a+1)^2 + b^2 vs a^2 + (b+1)^2. But it is not true, f(4) = 1^2 + 3^3, which is not update from 2^2 + 2^2.

Could we find an algorithm better than brute enumeration (O(n^2))?

Comment: @MrSmith42 Consider the (infinite) sequence of all numbers that can be written as a²+b², in increasing order. The OP is asking for the nth number in that sequence. For instance, the first terms in the sequence are 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, so the 0th term is 0, the 1st term is 1, the 2nd term is 2, the 3rd term is 4, etc

Comment: You probably want to find `n`th *smallest* `x` : `(1, 1) (2, 1) (2, 2) (3, 1) (3, 2) (4, 1) (3, 3)...`
`, so the 5th smallest `x` is `13` (`3^2 + 2^2`)

Comment: In other words, the OP is asking for the nth term in that sequence: https://oeis.org/A001481

Comment: Probably https://oeis.org/A000404

Comment: @MrSmith42 sorry smallest

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Could we find an algorithm better than brute enumeration (O(n^2))?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you call brute force, but the problem is probably solvable in time O(n) by exhaustive search.

Consider a square of side 2√n with a corner at the origin, compute all values inside this square, and set a bit in a bit array every time.

This takes a number of operations proportional to (2√n)² = 4n.

---

For this method to work, one must check if 2√n is large enough to generate the n first Pythagorean sums.

Comment: It turns out that 2 sqrt(n) is not big enough.

Comment: @btilly: do you know a safe bound ?

Comment: All primes that are `1 mod 4` are sums of 2 squares.  And the density of those is `1/(2 log(n))`.  So for large enough `n`, `2 n log(n)` will be an upper bound.  I bet there is a better one that is something like `O(n log(log(n))))`.  But I'll put up an answer showing how to lazily discover it without too much work, and also without crazy memory needs.

Answer (score 1):

A first algorithm idea would be to use a heap.

Intuitively, you know that the smallest a and b are, the smallest a²+b² will be. So:

- It's obvious at a glance that 10² + 3² < 10² + 4²
- It's not obvious at a glance whether 10²+3² <? 7²+8²

I suggest adding pairs (a,b) to a min-heap, slowly increasing a and b. Then, the next element in the sequence is the next element in the heap.

In the algorithm below, `/2` represents integer division by 2; for instance, `10/2` and `11/2` are both equal to `5`.

```
function nth_sum_of_two_nonzero_squares(n):
    heap <- empty min-heap
    for k in range [2 .. n+1]:
        for a in range [1 .. k/2]:
            push a² + (k-a)² to heap if it's not already in the heap
        next_term <- pop(heap)
    return next_term
```

Slight improvement: the smallest term added for a given `k` is for `a = k / 2`. We can leverage the knowledge of that value to avoid adding more candidates to the heap, as long as the current root of the heap is still smaller than this next candidate.

This gives us:

```
function nth_sum_of_two_nonzero_squares(n):
    heap <- empty min-heap
    i = 0
    k = 2
    push 1²+1² to heap
    loop forever:
        next_candidate = ((k+1)/2)² + ((k+2)/2)² = ((k+1)²+1)/2
        while next_candidate > peek(heap):
            i <- i + 1
            next_term = pop(heap)
            if i == n:
                return next_term
        k <- k + 1
        for a in range [1 .. k/2]:
            if a² + (k-a)² not already in heap:
                push a² + (k-a)² to heap
        i <- i+1
        next_term = pop(heap)
        if i == n:
            return next_term
```

The drawback is that we're adding more and more terms to the heap for every term we pop. Here it looks like the size of the heap is going to be quadratic in `k`. However, I am convinced that the maximum value of `k` is in the order of the square root of `n`. If that is true, then the algorithm uses only pseudo-linear-time and linear-space.

You might improve on this algorithm by trying to add fewer terms to the heap for every term which is popped. This would require more intuition as to how to sort pairs (a, b) in a pseudo-increasing order of a²+b².

Testing in python and comparing with [OEIS: Numbers that are the sum of 2 nonzero squares](https://oeis.org/A000404) for correctness:

```py
from heapq import heappush, heappop
from itertools import count, islice

def sums_of_two_nonzero_squares():
    heap = [2] # 2 == 1² + 1²
    seen = {2}
    for k in count(3):
        next_candidate = (k*k + 1)//2
        while heap and heap[0] < next_candidate:
            next_term = heappop(heap)
            yield next_term
            seen.remove(next_term)
        for a in range(1, k//2+1):
            x = a**2+(k-a)**2
            if x not in seen:
                seen.add(x)
                heappush(heap, x)

oeis_groundtruth = [    2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 18, 20, 25, 26, 29, 32, 34, 37, 40, 41, 45, 50, 52, 53, 58, 61, 65, 68, 72, 73, 74, 80, 82, 85, 89, 90, 97, 98, 100, 101, 104, 106, 109, 113, 116, 117, 122, 125, 128, 130, 136, 137, 145, 146, 148, 149, 153, 157, 160, 162, 164, 169, 170, 173, 178]

result = list(islice(sums_of_two_nonzero_squares(), len(oeis_groundtruth)))

print(result)
# [2, 5, 8, 10, 13, 17, 18, 20, 25, 26, 29, 32, 34, 37, 40, 41, 45, 50, 52, 53, 58, 61, 65, 68, 72, 73, 74, 80, 82, 85, 89, 90, 97, 98, 100, 101, 104, 106, 109, 113, 116, 117, 122, 125, 128, 130, 136, 137, 145, 146, 148, 149, 153, 157, 160, 162, 164, 169, 170, 173, 178]

print('result == oeis_groundtruth: ', (result == oeis_groundtruth))
# result == oeis_groundtruth:  True
```

Comment: This would be my first approach. But note that every heap operation is `O(log(k))`. Which makes this more than linear time. Also `k` grows slightly faster than `sqrt(n)` making space worse than you thought.

Comment: @btilly do you have some insight regarding how to find bounds on the growth of k?

Comment: I can place an upper bound `k = O(sqrt(n log(n)))`.  I can't prove a tighter bound, but I think the real one is `k = O(sqrt(n log(log(n))))`.  I will add the theory behind this to my answer.

Comment: Theory added to the end of my answer.

Comment: @btilly Well, if k = O(sqrt(n log(n))) then this algorithm uses O(k²) = O(n log(n)) space, and O(k² log(k)) = O(n log(n)²) time. That's almost as good as O(n).

Comment: Yes. Hence my "slightly faster".  However the solution that I posted uses a factor of `log(n)` less time, and roughly square root of the space.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on https://stackoverflow.com/a/74787074/585411.

If it returns `m` as an answer then it did `O(m)` work and needed `O(sqrt(m) log(m))` memory. As I commented to @yves-daoust, `m` is NOT `O(n)` but can be shown to be `O(n log(n))` and is probably something like `O(n log(log(n))))`.  So this is significantly better than quadratic.

```
import math

def nth_two_square(n):
    squares = [1, 4]
    high = 1

    while True:
        low = high + 1
        high = squares[-1]+1
        block = [False] * (high - low + 1)
        i = len(squares) - 1
        j = 0
        while squares[j] + squares[j] <= high:
            while high < squares[j] + squares[i]:
                i -= 1
            k = i
            while j <= k and low <= squares[j] + squares[k]:
                block[squares[j] + squares[k] - low] = True
                k = k-1
            j = j + 1

        for i in range(len(block)):
            if block[i]:
                n -= 1
                if n < 1:
                    return low + i

        to_add = int(math.log(squares[-1]))
        for _ in range(to_add):
            squares.append((len(squares)+1)*(len(squares)+1))

print(nth_two_square(1000000))
```

If instead of checking `n` to know which we return we'll get a version that can return the sequence in order.

```
def two_squares():
    squares = [1, 4]
    high = 1

    while True:
        low = high + 1
        high = squares[-1]+1
        block = [False] * (high - low + 1)
        i = len(squares) - 1
        j = 0
        while squares[j] + squares[j] <= high:
            while high < squares[j] + squares[i]:
                i -= 1
            k = i
            while j <= k and low <= squares[j] + squares[k]:
                block[squares[j] + squares[k] - low] = True
                k = k-1
            j = j + 1

        for i in range(len(block)):
            if block[i]:
                yield low + i

        to_add = int(math.log(squares[-1]))
        for _ in range(to_add):
            squares.append((len(squares)+1)*(len(squares)+1))

n = 100
for m in two_squares():
    print(m)
    n -= 1
    if n < 1:
        break
```

---

Some theory behind this which explains the comments that I've left on the other answers.

The set of complex numbers of the form `a + bi` with `a` and `b` integers are called the *Gaussian integers*.  Gaussian integers act a lot like integers, they have unique factorization into primes, and so on.  However Gaussian primes are a little different.

For a start, primes come in sets of four.  We consider two numbers to be the same prime if they are the same up to a factor of `1`, `i`, `-1` or `-i`.

Next, if a number is a sum of two squares, it can't be a Gaussian prime.  That is because `(a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2+b^2`.  Conversely if we can factor a number into Gaussian primes, then we can list all of its divisors.  It is a sum of two squares if and only if we can find a divisor of the form `a+bi`.

So the fact that `1^2+1^2 = 2` means that `2 = (1+i)(1-i)` is not a Gaussian prime. Ditto `5 = (1+4i)(1-4i)` is not either. But `7` IS a Gaussian prime.

The general result comes from a result by Fermat.  And it is that a prime in the integers is a Gaussian prime if and only if its remainder when divided by 3 is 1.  So `7`, `11`, and `19` are all Gaussian primes.  While `2`, `5`, `13`, and `17` are not.  (A further result is that all primes which are not Gaussian primes can be written as a sum of squares in one and only one way.)

Now suppose that `7` divides `a+bi` some number of times.  Then there is a `c+di` such that `(c+di)*7^k = a+bi`.  But then `(c-di)*7^k = a-bi` so it must divide `a-bi` at least as often.  Reversing the signs in the argument, we also find that `7` divides `a+bi` at least as often as it divides `a-bi`.  And therefore it divides `a+bi` and `a-bi` the **same** number of times.

From this we find that `7` always divides `a^2 + b^2` an **even** number of times.  And the same argument applies for all other primes that are also Gaussian primes.  (Here is where I start waving my hands, but you can trust that the argument can be formulized.)  About half the primes are congruent to `3 mod 4`, and your typical large integer will be divisible by at at least *one* of them an odd numbers of times.  And therefore the density of numbers that are the sum of 2 squares goes down for large numbers.

But it only goes down slowly.  The density of primes only declines like `1/log(n)`, and half of them are congruent to `1 mod 4`.  And therefore the density can't fall off faster than `1/(2 log(n))`.

And, of course, most sums of 2 squares aren't prime.  So it falls off slower than that.  I don't have a good estimate of that though, just an educated guess.